# Eclipse configuration proxy Name host not valid

Tags: eclipse, proxy, host

I work with Eclipse and I want to configure the proxy.

My configuration is

[image]

[image]

I want to remove the host's name of HTTPS but I get the message

```
Name host no valid
```

How can I remove the host of HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click *Borrar* (en: *Clear*) instead of *Editar...*  (en: *Edit...*)