# Eclipse configuration proxy Authentication required

Tags: eclipse, authentication, proxy

I work with eclipse and I want to install the update

```
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates-pre-3_8/releases/content.xml
```

I have a proxy .

My network connections configuration is

[image]

When I execute Help->Search updates

I get the error

```
HTTP Authentication proxy required http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates-pre-3_8/releases/content.xml
```

How do I have to configure the proxy?

Comment: Is your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45485357/6505250) answered (here the screenshot shows you solved the problem)?

Comment: Clicking clear I removed the server name. I solved this question. The password was  wrong

Comment: Then it would be nice to accept [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45485459/6505250). That would help others who have the same problem to find the answer.

Comment: It looks strange that you have two lines with _HTTP_. Maybe you have to _Restore Defaults_ and try again. Is this Windows (in most cases _Active Provider: Native_ should work also with a proxy)?